# Prism Forms difference between INavigatedAware and INavigatingAware?

Tags: xamarin.forms, navigation, prism

I'm using Prism Forms 7.x in a Xamarin Forms app. Up to now, I was using the INavigatedAware interface in view models to check if a navigation to or from the respective view model happened. Now, I saw that there is INavigatingAware, which only provides the OnNavigatingTo method (so, the navigation is not yet finished).

My questions regarding INavigatingAware.OnNavigatingTo:
- Can I use INavigatingAware where I'm not interested in the OnNavigatedFrom call?
- Is it better in terms of performance to load data within OnNavigatingTo (before the BindingContext is set; so that e.g. the data binding don't need to be updated twice)?

Would be nice to share your experiences and best practices regarding those two interfaces.

Answer (score 6):

INavigatingAware.OnNavigatingTo was first introduced to Prism to assist developers perform initialization logic similar to the `ViewWillAppear`.

To help better visualize this the events look something like this within the NavigationService:

- Create the Page
- Set the ViewModelLocator.Autowire property if it is null
- Apply any behaviors from the PageBehaviorFactory
- Call IConfirmNavigation.CanNavigate (and it's async counterpart) on the Page/ViewModel we're navigating away from
- Call INavigatingAware.OnNavigatingTo
- Push the page onto the NavigationStack
- Call INavigatedAware.OnNavigated{From|To}

#### BREAKING CHANGE

Now, all of that said, we have had a tremendous amount of feedback on INavigatingAware (the essence of this very question), as a result over the overwhelming feedback from the Prism community INavigatingAware has been a hard obsolete in Prism 7.2. This means that it was removed from INavigationAware, and will throw a compile time error if you directly implement it. For those times where you got it for free from INavigationAware, it simply will not be called. Moving forward, we have introduced a series of interfaces to make this easier and more self documenting as to the intent.

##### New Interfaces & API

- IInitialize.Initialize
- IInitializeAsync.InitializeAsync

The new IInitialize interface is the direct replacement for INavigatingAware. We have long gotten feedback that people would like the ability to perform async tasks during initialization. The issue here is that this can cause a very noticeable delay in Navigation similar to IConfirmNavigationAsync. If you use either of those async interfaces, you will need to be sure to include some sort of busy/loading overlay on your screen.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `INavigatedAware` and `INavigationAware`? I couldn't find any documentation on that

Comment: In the latest version of Prism there isn't a difference. INavigationAware has in the past been an aggregate marker interface. Internally Prism would actually look for the base interface like INavigatedAware. Previously there was an INavigatingAware which was replaced with IInitialize